# Why the type of hero is any if I have already typed it?

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with types. I fetched data from OpenDota API and use redux after I initialized my state and try to map it I have an error -

> **The hero parameter is implicitly of type "any"**.

Here is my code, please help me to handle with it:

```
const Heroes = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchHeroes());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const heroes = useAppSelector(state => state.heroes.heroes);

  console.log(heroes);

  const array = heroes.map(hero => {
    console.log(hero?.id);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is my type

```js
interface IHeroes {
  heroes: { [key: string]: any };
  err: string;
}

const initialState: IHeroes = {
  heroes: [],
  err: '',
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to be? You're typing it with any explicitly. You need to type it with whatever type you want a hero to have. If this addresses your issue, I'll write up an answer explaining what's happening here.

Comment: I don't what to type because it very big array with objetcts with more than 60 properties and what I need to type ? ``` interface IHero {
  id: string;
  localized_name: string;
  img: string;
  base_str: number;
  str_gain: number;
  base_agi: number;
  agi_gain: number;
  base_int: number;
  int_gain: number;
}```

Comment: You typed the `heroes` property as an object in the `IHeroes` interface and then as an array in the `initialState` variable; it should be giving you an error about that. If the `heroes` property is supposed to be an array, make it an array when you type it (i.e., `heroes: { [key: string]: any }[];` Or better yet, type out those 60 properties, if you need them all. Or use a tool that maps your type from whatever backend language you're using to TypeScript. Or refactor your types so they have fewer properties...

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, you can do it like this, by modifying your existing code -

```ts
interface IHeroes {
    heroes: Array<{ [key: string]: any }>;
    err: string;
}

const initialState: IHeroes = {
    heroes: [],
    err: '',
}
```

Or to be more explicit and creating a type for a hero -

```ts
type IHero = Record<string,any>; // OR `{ [key: string]: any }` both are same

interface IHeroes {
    heroes: Array<IHero>;
    err: string;
}

const initialState: IHeroes = {
    heroes: [],
    err: '',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why the type of hero is `any` if I have already typed it?

`hero` is of type `any` because that is exactly what you declared it to be.

```js
interface IHeroes {
  heroes: {
    [key: string]: any; // <-- each hero is this type
  };
  err: string;
}
```

If you want it to be anything *other than* `any` you'll need to defined/declare the type/interface yourself.

Example from your comment:

```js
interface IHero {
  id: string;
  localized_name: string;
  img: string;
  base_str: number;
  str_gain: number;
  base_agi: number;
  agi_gain: number;
  base_int: number;
  int_gain: number;
  // ... rest of the properties
}
```

```js
interface IHeroes {
  heroes: IHero[]; // or Array<IHero>
  err: string;
}
```